# Law of Excluded Middle in Logic Proof

Tags: logic, philosophy

I'm having some difficulty doing a proof for the following:

$$\neg A \vee \neg(\neg B \wedge (\neg A \vee B))$$

It is said that you could use the law of excluded middles.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just trying to simplify the expression given? Otherwise, I don't see what to prove.

Comment: @yunone: I think you have to prove that the expression is a tautology.

Comment: I think you can just apply De Morgan's laws and the distributive laws, and arrive at a tautology of the form $A \vee \sim A$

Comment: @Pel, ah ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Can someone please teach me how you edited my post to use those characters instead of the ones I was using?

Comment: @Kerx, you can right click on the characters and click show source. This will show you the typesetting code. Enclose these in $ to get them to format. For example, `$\neg A \vee \neg(\neg B \wedge (\neg A \vee B))$` is what is written above.

Comment: yunone, thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\neg A\lor\neg(\neg B\land(\neg A\lor B)) &\equiv \neg A\lor(B\lor\neg(\neg A\lor B))\\
&\equiv \neg A\lor(B\lor (A\land\neg B)) \\
&\equiv \neg A\lor((B\lor A)\land(B\lor\neg B)) \\
&\equiv \neg A\lor((B\lor A)\land \top) \\
&\equiv \neg A\lor(B\lor A)
\end{align*}
$$
where $B\lor\neg B\equiv\top$ by the law of excluded middle. Applying it again should show the original expression is a tautology, which I believe is what you want to prove.

Comment: yunone, can you please teach me how you used those characters to post this answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Kerx, see my comment on the original question. [AOPS has a good reference for common symbols](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols) used in $\LaTeX$, I suggest googling it to see the basics. They are not hard to pick up as you go. Viewing the source for the math here is a good way to pick it up too.

Comment: I understand your proof.  I guess the weird part is that in my logic course, we are using special ways to do our proofs.  We use tools such as Conjunction Introduction, Elimination; Disjunction Introduction, Elimination; Contradiction Introduction, etc.  And we have to cite the lines associated with them.

Comment: @kerx, I hope you can fill it in, as I've never really explicitly listed the tools I'm using, and I'm not too familiar with their names. I guess I first use De Morgan's laws, and double negative elimination in the first and second lines, distributivity of disjunction in the third, and eventually the domination laws.

Answer (score 2):

Using distributivity,

$\neg A \bigvee \neg((\neg B \bigwedge \neg A) \bigvee (\neg B \bigwedge B))$
$\equiv \neg A \bigvee \neg (\neg B \bigwedge \neg A)$
$\equiv \neg A \bigvee (B \bigvee A)$
$\equiv \neg A \bigvee A$

as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use LEM explicitly, then:

Case 1, B is true:

$$\begin{array} {rcl}
\lnot A \lor \lnot (\lnot B \land (\lnot A \lor B)) 
&\triangleright&
\lnot A \lor \lnot (\lnot \text{T} \land (\lnot A \lor \text{T})) \\
&\triangleright&
\lnot A \lor \lnot (\text{F} \land \text{T}) \\
&\triangleright&
\lnot A \lor \text{T} \\
&\triangleright&
\text{T} \\
\end{array}$$

Case 2, B is false:
$$\begin{array} {rcl}
\lnot A \lor \lnot (\lnot B \land (\lnot A \lor B)) 
&\triangleright&
\lnot A \lor \lnot (\lnot \text{F} \land (\lnot A \lor \text{F})) \\
&\triangleright&
\lnot A \lor \lnot (\text{T} \land \lnot A) \\
&\triangleright&
\lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot A \\
&\triangleright&
\text{T} \\
\end{array}$$

You can be even more explicit if you split it into 4 cases, for the values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I like the proof technique and layout. I think it would also come in handy looking for counterexamples (although there wouldn't be any for this problem).

Answer (score 0):

The following proof uses the law of the excluded middle (LEM) in a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) to prove the tautology:

[image]

---

Although not likely what the exercise was intending, another way of looking at this problem is to use [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) and [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to convert the original statement to the following:

$$A \to (\lnot B \to (A \land \lnot B))$$

Here is a proof of that:

[image]

This proof checker does not have the material implication rule, so I would not be able to show that approach directly using it.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: Tip: If you want a more elegant solution, use a proof by cases with $\lnot(\lnot B\land(\lnot A\lor B))$ and $(\lnot B\land(\lnot A\lor B))$ instead.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That looks like it would be worth trying. Thanks.